# "TypeError not a constructor" when upgrading project from Babel v5 to v6+

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs, es6-modules

I've been bashing my head against this brick wall for a day now so it's time to turn to SO for help I think!  I'm trying to update a project off babel v5, I'm starting off with this in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.8.21",

"test": "mocha --require babel/register",
```

I've tried to upgrade to babel both v6 and v7 with no success either time.  In both cases I end up with `TypeError: _application.ApplicationClient is not a constructor` when I attempt to run tests that worked fine with v5:

```
import { ApplicationClient } from '../src/wiotp/sdk/application';
...
let client = new ApplicationClient();
```

Using v6 as an example, I end up with the following in package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "mocha": "6.1.4",

"test": "mocha --require babel-core/register --timeout 5000",
```

and created a .babelrc file (none existed previously):

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

I've read a dozen or more articles trying to understand what is going on here, I've done and undone numerous suggested "fixes" based on Google searches for similar problems, but I'm starting from zero and finding it incredibly hard to get simple plain-English explanation of what the actual problem is for a start, and how babel is supposed to be configured here to resolve it. I'm guessing something that happened by default in v5 needs to be configured somehow in .babelrc now, but */shrugs/* no idea where to go from here now.

- [babel5 to babel6 branch compare](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-nodejs/compare/cleanup-babel5...cleanup-babel6)
- [babel5 to babel7 branch compare](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-nodejs/compare/cleanup-babel5...cleanup-babel7)

Any pointers for someone struggling to wrap his head around babel, let alone the differences between v5, 6, & 7?

Edit:

src/wiotp/sdk/application/index.js has this:

```
import { default as ApplicationClient } from './ApplicationClient';

export default {
  ApplicationClient
}
```

Where src/wiotp/sdk/application/ApplicationClient.js has a single class exported (I'm just trying to create an instance of that class in the test code):

```
export default class ApplicationClient extends BaseClient {
  constructor(config) {
```

Comment: As a guess, I would assume that `ApplicationClient` is defined or compiled into an arrow function using the new version of Babel, while the old one wasn't doing it. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Babel to know where to start with verifying and/or fixing this. Still, the "not a constructor" message usually comes from trying to use `new` with an arrow function.

Comment: There is no way to know what `../src/wiotp/sdk/application` exports. Please include that in the question as well.

Comment: In node babel will most likely convert the import into require calls. My guess is there is something on this part that is not working correctly in the way interops is supposed to work between es6 and common.js. Note that since babel 7 they moved into scoped packages under the `@babel` org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> src/wiotp/sdk/application/index.js has this:
>
> ```
> import { default as ApplicationClient } from './ApplicationClient';
>
> export default {
>   ApplicationClient
> }
> ```

This is horrible, and causing your problem. That module does default-export an object literal, instead of just using named exports. It might be a bug and they meant to write either

```
import { default as ApplicationClient } from './ApplicationClient';
export { ApplicationClient }
```

or

```
export { default as ApplicationClient } from './ApplicationClient';
```

It would recommend to report an issue and provide a patch.

If this is not considered a bug but was done on purpose, you will need to change your code to

```
import application from '../src/wiotp/sdk/application';
…
let client = new application.ApplicationClient();
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or just import it directly from the original module:

```
import ApplicationClient from '../src/wiotp/sdk/application/ApplicationClient.js';
//                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
…
let client = new ApplicationClient();
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, and for the explanation of what was going on, it's really helped me understand what was going on here.